# Angular material sidenav closes on smartphone

Tags: jquery, angular-material

I have the following code

### Page.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="MyApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.3/angular-material.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:300,400,500,700,400italic">

    <!-- Base url for all relative links -->
    <base href="/test/" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div layout="column" flex ng-controller="MainController">
        <md-toolbar layout="row">
            <button ng-click="toggleSidenav('sidenav')" class="menuBtn">
                <span class="visually-hidden">Menu</span>
            </button>
            <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools" layout-align-gt-sm="center">Hello, World</h1>
        </md-toolbar>

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div layout="row" flex>
            <md-sidenav layout="column" class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="sidenav">

                <div id="content">
                    <md-content layout-padding flex class="md-padding">
                          ... some content here ...
                    </md-content>
                </div>
            </md-sidenav>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.3/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

### App.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial','ngMessages']);

    app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$mdSidenav', function($scope, $mdSidenav){
        $scope.toggleSidenav = function(menuId) {
            $mdSidenav(menuId).toggle();
        };
    }]);

})();
```

The problem is that on mobile devices **only** (on pc it works well) whenever I expand the sidebar it automatically closes. Where am I wrong?

Comment: <md-sidenav layout="column" class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="sidenav" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')"> Could you try this

Comment: with that attribute it will be always open on device whose screen is bigger than small..It wouldn't solve the problem

Comment: i thought thats what the issue if, that your sidenav is getting hidden on mobile devices

Comment: @Pratik the problem is that as soon as I click on the button the navbar opens (which is correct) and closes (this is the problem)

Comment: Oh okay!.I am not able to emulate the same in a fiddle. Its giving me errors. :/

Comment: Probably is the reference to angular.js and app.js files, which are local referencs (but you can use CDN version 1.3.15 for the first one, and for the second one you have the code above)

Comment: I removed those references. The JS section in the fiddle will represent app.js and i used angular from fiddle.